# can't save changes when deleting Routing App Coverage File

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to remove the Routing App Coverage .geojson file. Every-time I try to remove this and save changes, I get this error:

> We’re temporarily unable to save your changes. Please try again
>   later.

It's been 2 days now. I still can't remove it. If I try to change any other field in the app submission form, it works. Just not the Routing file.

Here is what happened that led to this point:

1. I tried to submit an app with a valid .geojson file
2. I got an Invalid Binary error and the app was not submitted. This is because my app does not support routing.
3. I try to remove the Routing .geojson file from my submission form.
4. It doesn't work. I keep getting the error " We’re temporarily unable to save your changes. Please try again later. "
5. Error keeps occurring after 2 days.

I have no idea what is wrong. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you have solved this, but I had the same problem. Just inspect the element (that pop-up that appears on top of the Routing App coverage), delete the element from browser's tree and press the delete button.

Comment: I dont' think it was as easy for me. I tried different browsers and machines, but the problem kept persisitng. Evenually, i had to contact apple support to get this fixed